# What happens when my data size is more than my table column size?

Tags: oracle11g, size

I am using oracle db. I have some basic doubt, I have created a table with column
comments VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE).If i tried to insert a value that having 2500 bytes
what will happen? whether

```
1. It will throw an exception(please give me exception details).
2. It will truncate the 500 bytes data. and insert only first 2000 bytes.
3. Internally it will increases it size and insert entire data.
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Did you try it? You can very quickly make a test in SQL*Plus.

Comment: Or use SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49aae/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ORA-12899: value too large for column.